# dotnet core 2.0 ProjectReference error

Tags: reference, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

When using dotnet core 2.0-preview1 in vs2017. I got an error about project reference.

I hava a solution with two projects.

[image]

This is `Common.Bll` Project

[image]

The `Common.Web` referenced the project `Common.Bll`. But the ide told me cannot find `Common.Bll` with error `Using directive is not required by the code and can be safely removed. Cannot resolve symbol 'Bll'`

This is `Common.Web` project

[image]

[Common.Bll.csproj](https://gist.github.com/lon-yang/21bac37308271a2509b5fd772323bef6#file-common-bll-csproj)

[Common.Web.csproj](https://gist.github.com/lon-yang/72f1f52f391bf122ddd8248f5434a87e#file-common-web-csproj)

**But it can be build succeed and run normally.**
Have any way to solve this?

### update:

It's working follow the @Svek to change the `Common.Bll` from `netstandard2.0` to `netcoreapp2.0`.

Comment: Can you show the code for the `class` under the `Common.Bll` namespace that you are trying to reference?

Comment: In package manager run: `Update-Package -reinstall`... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

Comment: Still not working after run `Update-Package -reinstall`. The csproj file is added.

Comment: In your `Common.Bll` change `netstandard2.0` to `netcoreapp2.0`

Comment: It's working. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your csproj file

Visual Studio doesn't like to behave quite right when the `TargetFramework` does not totally match up.

**Common.Bll.csproj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Common.Web.csproj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

> Make both of them the same, and you should be good to go.

---

the error:

> ```
> cannot resolve symbol '<  >'
> ```

**The simple solution is to reinstall all your packages**, and make sure all your dependencies are properly showing up in Visual Studio under each project. (Dependencies --> Projects | or | Dependencies --> Assemblies).

**In Package Manager**

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

*More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) to reinstall your packages.*

---

### Reference to  an unused library

**- *Update: You can ignore this. Your updated question makes this section no longer apply.* -**

Until you are actually using a library, Visual Studio will inform you that the referenced library is not required.

> ```
> using directive is not required by the code and can be safely removed.
> ```

You can do one of two things:

**1.) Use the library that you are referencing**

In your case:

```
var obj = new Common.Bll.<Your Class>;
```

**2.) Remove library that you are referencing**

This can be done quickly by right-clicking and selecting `Remove Unused Usings`.

[image: Remove Unused Usings]

The alternative is to use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+G`.

Comment: It's not working when using `new Common.Bll.UserBiz()`. And in the dependencies we can found the reference of `Common.Bll`. I have updated the question and added the dependencies. thanks

Comment: Did you restore your packages first?